# blueman-manager not starting

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Bluetooth was not working on my Ubuntu 20.04. So after reading some other answers on this forum and installing some packages, when I run `blueman-manager` it doesn't start and gives the [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dktHW.png).

The output of command `$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status` -

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

And for command `$sudo rfkill list` -

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How can I make Bluetooth work properly in my system?

Answer (score 0):

First see bluetooth.service status;

> $ sudo systemctl status bluetooth

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

If the terminal shows that, you need to do this;

> $ sudo systemctl enable bluetooth && sudo systemctl start bluetooth

And done!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Bluetooth is enabled on your system.

```bash
systemctl status blueman.service
```

If it's not running, you can start it with:

```bash
sudo systemctl start blueman.service
```

You can also reset blueman.

```bash
rm -rf ~/.config/blueman
sudo systemctl restart blueman.service
```

If none of the above solutions works, try reinstalling Blueman. You can do this with the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install --reinstall blueman
```

Hope this might help.